# run: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid connection string attribute

Tags: java

Below is the sample code that I have and it works fine, but with *Windows 7 home premium 64bit* on my laptop it doesn't. I get the following error:

```
run:
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid connection string attribute
```

I am using *NetBeans*.

```
package javaapplication1;

import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class DBDemo1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String sourceURL = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}DBQ=UserDB.mdb;";
            Connection userDB = DriverManager.getConnection(sourceURL, "admin", "");
            Statement myStatement = userDB.createStatement();
            String writeString = "INSERT INTO Users(Firstname, Surname, Id) VALUES('Fred', 'Bloggs', 'bf01')";
            myStatement.executeUpdate(writeString);

            ResultSet results = myStatement.executeQuery("SELECT Firstname, Surname, Id FROM Users ORDER BY Id");

            while (results.next())
            {
                out.print(results.getString(1) + " ");
                out.print(results.getString(2) + " ");
                out.println(results.getString(3));
            }
            results.close();
        }
        //The following exceptions MUST be caught
        catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe)
        {
            out.println(cnfe);
        }
        catch(SQLException sqle)
        {
            out.println(sqle);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your `sourceURL` is missing a semi-colon `;`:

```
String sourceURL = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=UserDB.mdb;";
                                                                      ^
```

Comment: it come out tis java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Could not find file '(unknown)'.

Comment: This is a different error now. Is your `UserDB.mdb` located in the same folder as your application or working directory?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String sourceURL = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}DBQ=UserDB.mdb;DriverID=22";
```